# (Over)plotting points on a line plot

Tags: plot, idl-programming-language

I am trying to plot individual data points on a line plot I already made as follows:

```
p=plot('3.29*exp(-17.4*(x^2))-0.908',xrange=[0.,1.],yrange=[-1.,1.5])
```

I first tried overplotting a point like this but nothing appears on the graph

```
estimate1=plot([0.549],[0.755],overplot=1)
```

When I give the plot function two points to overplot by adding another set of x and y values in input vectors, it connects them.

```
estimate=plot([0.349,0.9595],[0.555,0.9995],overplot=1)
```

How can I (over)plot the points without them being connected?
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the scatterplot function? It also has the overplot keyword: https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/scatterplot.html

Comment: @jitter, thank you for your input. I am using the `equation` property of the plot function to let IDL generate data points to draw the thick line in the fig above. I don't believe the scatterplot function has this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set `linestyle = 6` which will plot without the line.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around the problem I was having. After choosing a symbol for the points I wanted to show, I simply set the transparency of the line connecting them to 100 and the symbol transparency to 0.

```
estimate1.symbol='diamond'
estimate1.transparency=100
estimate1.sym_transparency=0
```

The work around is not elegant, but it works.